# $S=\frac{-d^2}{dx^2}$ self-adjoint operator or not?

Tags: operator-theory

I have this simple question :

In $L^2(]0,1[)$ let $S$ be the operator defined by :

$D(S)=C_c^2(]0,1[)$  and

$S=\frac{-d^2}{dx^2}$

is this operator self adjoint, and how to prove it   ?

($C_c$ : functions with compact support)

(I think that no, as what i read in the article that i follow)

thanks .....

Comment: can you also include the defintion of self-adjoint?

Comment: try to use integration by part. Twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is only symmetric, but not selfadjoint because the domain is too small. If it was selfadjoint, there would exist $f\in D(S)$ such that $-f'' + if = 1$, but there isn't such an $f$ because $-f'' + if$ has compact support, while $1$ has not.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by symmetric but not self-adjoint as this could never happen in finite dimensional space

Comment: This is right. But the present space is infinite-dimensional, where this can happen when the operator in not everywhere defined.

Comment: BTW: For many physicists this operator *is* selfadjoint. They don't care too much about domains. ;-)

Comment: One definition of self-adjoint is that the ranges of $S-i$ and $S+i$ are the whole space. The Answer would be more helpful if it were explained how the domain is insufficient.

Comment: @M.luffy If the answer was satisfactory for you, please check it as done.

Comment: @KeithMcClary As far as I can see, I did exactly that.